# Namespacing in C with structs

Tags: c, namespaces

It is possible to imitate namespaces in C like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct math_namespace {
    double (*sin)(double);
};
const struct math_namespace math = {sin};

int main() {    
    printf("%f\n", math.sin(3));

    return 0;
}
```

Are there any disadvantages to this, or just situations where a prefix makes more sense? It just seems cleaner to do it this way.

Comment: `sin` has type `double sin(double)`, you should change the type or use `sinf`.

Comment: Interesting approach. But I think it's just as damaging to readability as prefixes are. The main disadvantage I see is that you'd get a runtime error if a function pointer isn't initialized, rather than a linkage error.

Comment: It introduced one more indirection, or not? (with time-penalty?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is already used in real projects such as the [C Containers Library](http://ccl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) by Jacob Navia. C is not designed for object-oriented programming. This is not really efficient, since you have to (1) access to the structure and (2) dereference the function pointer. If you really want prefixes, I think changing your identifiers remains the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this style for a while now. It helps organize the program without all of the excess baggage of an OOP language. There is no performance penalty because accessing a function pointer in C is the same as directly accessing the function. I like it enough that I even wrote a very short paper about it. It can be found on http://slkpg.1eko.com under the link "C with Structs" at the bottom of the page. 
The direct link is http://slkpg.1eko.com/cstructs.html.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? One disadvantage is all the setting up which could go out of sync, and also to add to the namespace you have to change the structure.

And there's no 'using namespace' so you always have to specify it. What about and functions with different parameter types?

Comment: What *about* functions with different parameter types?

Comment: What do you mean by reinventing the wheel? Using C++ is not an option due to project requirements.

Comment: @Overv - Sounds like you should review the project requirements! If you are supposed to write C code for a reason, do that. Don't invent yet another language

Comment: @BoPersson I'm writing a compiler for my own language designed to easily interact with C code. C++ with its complexities and lacking ABI compatibility is unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this *does* allow you to export your namespace and it *does* allow a client module to use a static or local version of something that's named `sin`.  So, in that sense, it does actually work.

The downside is that it's not terribly ELF-friendly. The struct initialization is buried in the middle of a writable data page, and it needs to be patched up. Unless you are statically linking, this is a load-time fix-up. On the bright side, it just duplicates what the ELF dispatch table would have done, so I bet it isn't even any slower. On Windows I think the considerations are similar.